# adding links to e-commerece vendors on your website

Tags: html, css, c#-4.0

I have made a book website for my final semester project and I wanted to add the following functionality to it :

I display information about a book, I want to add links to different vendors where the user can buy the books. For e.g. I could put links to amazon, ebay etc. Once the user clicks on it, he would be directed to that specific website but with the product page open on it.

Do I have to use a API for the same or I can just append stuff to the url and achieve the same effect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if half the questions posted on SO are made by bots.

Comment: this one is not, I can assure of that

Comment: You have a list of books.  Where is that stored?  In a database?  When a user opens your book page do you want to automatically generate a link to view the product on multiple vendor pages?

Comment: the book data comes from an API. It is not stored anywhere. When I am displaying book details, I want to dynamically generate links to various vendors and put that in my book detail page. so for the 2nd part of your comment - yes.

Comment: Where is this book data coming from and what data do you have access to?  It sounds to me like you just need to hit the API of the vendor (if available) that you want to use.  Amazon:  https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html.  Ebay:  http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/FindingAPIGuide.html.  I'm not really sure what your question is...

Comment: if you want to give link to a google serach result, you just append the word to the end of this url "http://google.com?q=", and you get the required page. I was thinking if you can do the same for Amazon and Ebay without getting into the API.

Comment: Just go to Amazon & Ebay, perform a search and see what the resulting URL is.  I wouldn't do it this way myself, but, again, this question isn't very clear.

Comment: hmm well it does not work for Amazon or ebay. They generate a cryptic url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of sites do have an url api, but often times require some sort of token you pass along to access their data. And it's pretty much a guarantee each site will be different in how they structure those urls. It also depends on what data you have to make that query. Author? Title? ISBN?

However, if you are just looking to have some quick results you can do a search on the site and analyze the url to figure out a general query to work with. For example I just went to look at Amazon and ebay:

For Amazon I did a search and realized the ISBN was in the string. So I created a few custom urls:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0765325950/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765325950)
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449331815](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449331815)
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0441013597/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441013597)

That isn't a cryptic number, but the ISBN-10 for those books. And here is a keyword search:
http://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=enders%20game
(the %20 is url encoding for a space)

Ebay is a bit different. Here are some queries:
Keyword: [http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=wheel+of+time](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=wheel%20of%20time)
Keyword: [http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=the+hunt+for+red+october](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=the%20hunt%20for%20red%20october)

Some other sites I tried:
Keyword: [http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s/war+and+peace](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s/war%20and%20peace)
ISBN-13: [www.barnesandnoble.com/s/9781449331818](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s/9781449331818)
ISBN-10: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s/0812550706
ISBN-13: http://www.booksamillion.com/p/9780618260300
ISBN-10: http://www.booksamillion.com/p/1476714789

So just replace the relevant part of the url: keywords, ISBN-10, ISBN-13, for any of those services and you should be good to go. Note that this is NOT a long term solution. You should really be using the services API's, but since this is just a school project. Good enough IMHO.

Comment: what would be the parallel format on barnesandnoble and booksamillion for 10 digit isbn ?

Comment: @user590849 I took another look just now. It seems like for BAM and B&N you can simplify the url even more! I've updated my original answer. Hope that helps. Best of success on your project.